# System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on __Share

Tags: salesforce, apex-code

I have created share object in my salesforce environment.
From Setup-> security  Controls -> Sharing Settings -> I made my custom object access to "Private". So suppose my object name is EVT_Client__c & I am trying to insert data into EVT_Client__Share from trigger(AfterInsert) I am unable to do it. I am getting error as given below.

Once data get inserted into EVT_Client__c object our trigger tries to insert data into EVT_Client__share object but we are getting error. Profile user who is inserting data into EVT_Client__c object through UI having Read/create/edit/delete access on object.

> System.TypeException: DML operation INSERT not allowed on
>   EVT_Client__Share

My code in trigger is as below in which I am getting error.

```
    public with sharing class EVT_Client_TriggerHandler {
    private void ShareClientToThirdPartyJobGroup(List<EVT_Client__c> lstClients){
    List<EVT_Client__Share> lstSharesForThirdPartyGroup = new List<EVT_Client__Share>();
    List<Group> lstThirdPartyGroups = [Select Id, RelatedId from Group where Name = 'Third Party'];

    for(EVT_Client__c client: lstClients){
        for(Group roleGroup : lstThirdPartyGroups ){
              EVT_Client___Share objShareForThirdPartyGroup = new EVT_Client__Share(ParentId = client.Id, 
                  UserOrGroupId = roleGroup.Id, 
                  AccessLevel = 'Edit', 
                  RowCause = Schema.EVT_Client__Share.RowCause.User_Client__Access__c);
          lstSharesForThirdPartyGroup.add(objShareForThirdPartyGroup);
        }   
    }

    insert lstSharesForThirdPartyGroup;
}
}
```

Comment: I found issue. By changing code from `public with sharing class EVT_Client_Assessment_TriggerHandler`  to `public class EVT_Client_Assessment_TriggerHandler` works correctly

Answer (score 0):

You're sure it's not a "detail" in any master-detail relationship? The OWD would then say "controlled by parent" instead of "private". Can you switch to Classic view, go to page layout and verify the `[Sharing]` button can be added, displays OK, this user can manually share this record from UI?

Post your code sample? I suspect you need to define [Apex Sharing Reason](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_apex_sharing_reasons.htm&type=5) first. It's bit like roles if you ever played with Account/Contact/Opportunity/Case roles.

Once it's set you should be able to do something like this code sample: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm (they use "manual" as sharing reason but you might have more luck with custom sharing reason.

---

I quickly created your object and this worked like a charm for me:

```
trigger Stack57201752 on EVT_Client__c (after insert) {

    List<Group> groups = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name = 'Third Party'];
    List<EVT_Client__Share> shares = new List<EVT_Client__Share>();
    for(EVT_Client__c c : trigger.new){
        for(Group g : groups){
            shares.add(new EVT_Client__Share(
                ParentId = c.Id, 
                UserOrGroupId = g.Id, 
                AccessLevel = 'Edit', 
                RowCause = 'Manual'
            ));
        }
    }
    insert shares;
}
```

And when I click the `[Sharing]` button on the record it looks good:

[image]

---

**So... Stupid question time:** have you clicked this checkbox?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for update, I have posted post with code. OWD having only three option (private , "public read only" & 'public read/write") for my custom object.